# Who sent message on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus

Is there a way to tell who is sending messages to an Azure Service Bus Topic?  We are receiving a null message each day at the same time and we would like to try and figure out who is sending it?
Cheers
Stew

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OP's mailbox. Not related to programming at all.

Comment: It may or may not be related to programming.  There seems to be a lot you can do with the Azure API that you cannot do with it's Services Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've double checked the REST API reference and can't see any values that are coming back that could be used to track this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard message property to determine the sender identity. If you own the application on both sender / receiver, you can add a custom message property on the BrokeredMessage to identify a sender.